# Changing timezone for lambdas to EST?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I went into the environment variables for my lambdas and changed `TZ` to `EST`. My question is, is that valid? I keep seeing people do stuff like `America/Florida` for example. What if I just want a blanket timezone instead of specify a location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Lambda env var docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime):  TZ – The environment's time zone (UTC). The execution environment uses NTP to synchronize the system clock... The keys for these environment variables are reserved and cannot be set in your function configuration.

So the environment uses UTC.  Use your runtime language to handle time zone conversions.

For example, Python:

```py
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from datetime import datetime
    
dt_ny = datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo('America/New_York'))
dt_est = dt_ny.astimezone(ZoneInfo('EST'))
print(dt_ny)  # 2021-12-08 15:01:38.958676-05:00
print(dt_est) # 2021-12-08 15:01:38.958676-05:00
print(dt_ny == dt_est) # True during the winter, False in summer
```

The [IANA timezone database's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) `America/Florida`-style formats are widely supported in programming languages.  Unlike the `Z+2:00` format or `EST`, they don't get messed up by Summer Time ("Daylight Saving Time").  Even though `EST` is the same as `America/New_York` today, it won't during the summer, when New York switches to `EDT`.  Time zones seem dead simple until you start working with them.